# Android GPS locking and sensing

Tags: android, gps

I wrote an Android GPS application, that requests a location update every 20 seconds using GPS as the provider. I also added a GPS status listener to monitor the available satellites and their SNR.

I noticed that the `GPSstatuslistener` remains updating the satellites' information all the time (i.e. not every 20 seconds)!

My questions are:

1. Does this mean that the GPS sensor is always on or does it sleep between every 20 second interval?
2. The GPS location invocation consists of two stages a) locking, and b) sensing/reporting. In the android does the `GPSstatuslistener` do the locking and the `requestLocationUpdate` do the sensing?

Comment: You location updating each 20 seconds does not mean the GPS chip is off for 19 seconds. It is actually on. The "every 20 seconds" thing is mostly your to make.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If you see gps icon in status bar all the time then it means GPS is on and used, you can do it  programmatically by `removeUpdates`
2. a)Locking is done automatically by device and Android OS.

   b)Sensing means if you are talking about location information then it is done by `requestLocationUpdates()`. However information about GPS and its status is done by GPSstatusListener